# Linux CP using AWK output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cp

I have been trying to learn more about Linux and have spent this morning focusing on the awk command. the command I have been trying to get to work is below.

```
ls -lRt lpftp.* | awk '{print $7, $9}' | mkdir -p $(awk '{print $1}') | ls -lRt lpftp.* | cp $(awk '{print $9, $7}')
```

Essentially I am trying to move each file in a directory into a sub directory based on that files last modified day. The command first prints only the files I want, then uses mkdir to create a folder based on the day of the month it was last modified. What I want to do after that is move each file into its associated directory, however as the command is now it moves every file into the 01 folder and prints out the following text

```
cp: 0653-436  12 is a directory.
    Specify -r or -R to copy.
```

once for every directory.

does anyone know how I can fix this issue? or if there is a better way to go about it?

Comment: Why are you piping the output of `mkdir` to `ls`? `mkdir` doesn't produce any output (other than error messages) and `ls` doesn't use its input.

Comment: the reason for the second LS statement was because, after mkdir, I couldn't get access to the file name from the original LS, so I ran it again in order to recreate that list. is there a better method?

Comment: @Cronisej Yes, see my answer.

Comment: @Cronisej I understand why you have the second `ls` statement. What I don't understand is why you pipe something into it, instead of just running it as a separate command.

Comment: E.g. `ls ... | awk ... | mkdir; ls ... | awk ... | cp ...`

Comment: @Barmer to be perfectly honest I didn't even think about that. I was focused on other parts of the code and didn't consider why I was piping the output.

Comment: While minor, there is also technically a race condition if you use two separate `ls` commands (whether done correctly or not).  i.e., what if the first file of the day gets created just after the first `ls` command finishes?  Then you'd have a `cp` command queued up to copy a file into a directory that doesn't exist.  It's best to use one set of output for both the directory creation and the file copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls -lRt lpftp.* | awk '{print $7, $9}' | while read day file ; do mkdir -p "$day"; cp "$file" "$day"; done`

The commands between `do` and `done` will be executed for each line of output, with the first thing `awk` prints in the `day` variable and the second in `file` (per line).  I used quotes here somewhat unnecessarily, as there will not be spaces in the variables given the method by which they are set.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do something like this -- and the fastest to execute -- is to use awk on the data to output a shell script.  In awk, print the `mkdir` and `cp` commands you expect to execute.  Pipe the results into **head**(1) until you're satisfied.  Maybe look at the whole thing in **less**(1).  Then execute as follows:

```
ls -lRg lpfpt.* | awk script.awk | sh -ex
```

That will echo the commands to standard error, and stop on the first error.  If you're super absolutely sure it's right, drop the `x` option.

The advantage of this approach over a loop or a bunch of subprocesses in awk (with the `system` function) is:

- you can see what's going to happen, and what's happening
- speed of execution